# PyTorch's DataLoader returning the same set of labels for each batch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, apple-m1, pytorch-dataloader

I'm using PyTorch to train a model.
My validation_labels (ground truth labels) consists of the following values:

```
tensor([2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2,
        1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0,
        2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2,
        1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0,
        1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2,
        0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2,
        1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0,
        1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2,
        2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1,
        1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0,
        2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 1, 0, 0], device='mps:0')
```

But, using the below code to generate a DataLoader results in all the validation_labels being converted to '2's.

```
validation_data = TensorDataset(validation_inputs, validation_masks, validation_labels)
validation_sampler = SequentialSampler(validation_data)
validation_dataloader = DataLoader(validation_data, sampler=validation_sampler, batch_size=batch_size)

for step, batch in enumerate(validation_dataloader):
            batch = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)
            eval_data, eval_masks, eval_labels = batch
            print(eval_labels)
```

The eval labels get printed as:

```
tensor([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], device='mps:0')
tensor([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], device='mps:0')
tensor([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], device='mps:0')
tensor([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], device='mps:0')
tensor([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], device='mps:0')
tensor([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], device='mps:0')
tensor([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], device='mps:0')
tensor([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], device='mps:0')
tensor([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], device='mps:0')
tensor([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], device='mps:0')
tensor([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], device='mps:0')
tensor([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], device='mps:0')
tensor([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], device='mps:0')
tensor([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], device='mps:0')
tensor([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], device='mps:0')
```

Why are all the labels being changed to '2'? I'm not able to find out what is wrong with my code. Could someone tell me why this happens and what I should do about it?

Comment: I think it is due to the device. It seems that there is some bug on mps (see [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/77849) for instance). I reproduced your code on cpu and cuda and there was no problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because the folder I was passing to the dataloder was the parent folder of the actual training data. i.e. Data was present in training/training. By removing the outer layer, the dataloder was able to read the labels correctly.